# Calculating average wait time per message in a topic with PromQL

Tags: websphere, prometheus, grafana, promql

We collect the following two prometheus metrics over time:
The first is:

```
# HELP was_sib_durableSubscription_messageWait_time_seconds_total Total amount of time (in seconds) spent on the bus by messages consumed from this subscription.
# TYPE was_sib_durableSubscription_messageWait_time_seconds_total gauge
```

The second is:

```
# HELP was_sib_durableSubscription_messageWait_total The number of messages that waited on the bus.
# TYPE was_sib_durableSubscription_messageWait_total counter
```

We tried dividing the two metrics but the result does not seem to be right.

How can we create a graph that shows the average wait time per message that waited on the bus?

Comment: Hm. Your metrics look strange: they don't follow convention on the naming (`_total` postfix supposed to denote metrics of type counter) and I'd expect time metric to be counter, and count one to be gauge. (Or I don't understand what it supposed to mean)

Comment: Totally agree with you but this is out of my control :-)

Comment: Well, without understanding what data your metrics actually represent it's hard to help you. Usually you don't use raw values of counter, so might try something like `..._time_seconds_total/increase(..._messageWait_total [1m])`, but this is shooting into the dark.

Comment: The truth is that the ...time_seconds_total is always increasing even though it is described as gauge. So I agree with you the metrics definitions are not so clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following PromQL query returns the average wait time over the last 10 minutes:

```
increase(was_sib_durableSubscription_messageWait_time_seconds_total[10m])
  /
increase(was_sib_durableSubscription_messageWait_total[10m])
```

It uses [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/#increase) function for calculating the increase of wait time sum and wait time measurements over the last 10 minutes (such metrics are called [counters](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#counter)).

It also uses [`/` operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#arithmetic-binary-operators) for dividing the sum of wait times over the last 10 minutes by the number of wait time measurements during the last 10 minutes.

If you need calculating the average wait time over another lookbehind window, then just replace `10m` in the query above with the needed duration. See [the list of supported durations in PromQL](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-durations).

P.S. If the `was_sib_durableSubscription_messageWait_total` counter changes slowly over time, then `increase()` over this counter in Prometheus may return unexpected results because of extrapolation - see [this issue](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746) for details. The workaround is to use `increase()` function from VictoriaMetrics - this is Prometheus-like monitoring solution I work on. It doesn't use extrapolation in `increase()` function. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/) for more details.